# How to display different images in React MUI Box based on xs sm grid classes

Tags: reactjs, mui-x

I am setting my react mui box background as below

```
            <Box
              sx={{
                backgroundImage: `url("./letter2.png")`,
                backgroundRepeat: `no-repeat`,
                backgroundSize: "cover",
                height: "100%",
                width: "70%",
              }}
            >
              <div>
                    <TypeAnimation
                      sequence={[...
           </Box>
```

This is ok for desktops, but for mobile this image is very large.

Is there a way similar to this ->  direction={{ xs: 'column', sm: 'row' }} (where different image names be specified?)

Note: As you see Box already has {{}} for sx

Please advice how I can use a different scaled image ( theme based?)

Comment: Are you asking if there are two images, 'lion.jpg' and 'tiger.jpg,' and you want to display the 'lion.jpg' image in xs size and the 'tiger.jpg' image in small (sm) size? Please clarify if this is the correct understanding of your question?

Comment: Goal is display only 1 image in the background, .that fits mobile and desktop. As a workaround, I have image1 and image1_m , width of desktop could be 1024 , image1_m is like 480px. Did I clarify? ( you can think lion is desktop and tiger is mobile, that is not a problem)